# Basic KVL question

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

I'm trying to derive the output resistance of a common-source MOSFET with source degeneration. Are my KVL equations correct? I feel like it's very wrong.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you've drawn the common-source amplifier correctly.

Comment: It's a very peculiar situation. Can you check if my KVL equations are correct?#

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. The test voltage source must be ground referenced.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense, we don't have a complete loop! One last thing, is my second KVL equation correct - V1 + Vrs = 0?